# Name the images that i get from a web site in Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, count, filenames, string-length

I am scraping a web site and as a last part, I get their product images to the folder. I want to name these images like (product_id + numberOfImages) I mean if product has a 2 images, there will be 2 png like (productId_1) (productId_2).

I have productId and also images there is no problem. I just want to know how to name it as I want. Here is my code.

```java
for(Element imageElement : imageElements){
    String strImageURL = imageElement.attr("src"); 
    String strImageName =product_id + "_" + ??;
    try {
        URL urlImage = new URL(strImageURL);
        InputStream in = urlImage.openStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n = -1;
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( IMAGE_DESTINATION_FOLDER + "/" + strImageName );
        while ( (n = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ){
            os.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }

        //close the stream
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("sponsored product");
    }

    // for loop images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking what to write instead of the `??` in the code in your question. Just create a *counter* variable.

```java
int counter = 0;
for(Element imageElement : imageElements){
    String strImageURL = imageElement.attr("src"); 
    String strImageName = product_id + "_" + (++counter);
    try {
        URL urlImage = new URL(strImageURL);
        InputStream in = urlImage.openStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n = -1;
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( IMAGE_DESTINATION_FOLDER + "/" + strImageName );
        while ( (n = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ){
            os.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }

        //close the stream
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("sponsored product");
    }

    // for loop images
}
```